# Battery problems with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Tags: 22.04, power-management, battery

I am having little issue with battery or UI. I am having dual boot Windows/Ubuntu on my HP Elitebook. On UI it shows me that battery isn't charging but its on 98% for 5 hours now.

[image]

When I run: `upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`
this is what I get:

```
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               pending-charge
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              43,8438 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         44,4098 Wh
    energy-full-design:  53,0145 Wh
    energy-rate:         0 W
    voltage:             12,523 V
    charge-cycles:       30
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            83,7691%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-charging-symbolic'
```

Does anybody know how can I fix this? Thank you!

Comment: I have exactly the same issue - HP 14 Stream - same Ubuntu distro - no problem until update - now only thing that cures it for a while is a 15 second hold on the restart button- having shut it down - plus plug in prior to 15 seconds . .hopeless . .tried all sorts

Comment: Where are you getting this path `/org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0`? There isn't even any `/org` path on any linux system I've ever used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in fact normal behaviour for most laptops.

Batteries deteriorate if they are unnecessarily charged. There’s little point charging from 98 to 100%, but will cause better wear.

Clearly the power supply is working as your battery isn’t discharging despite using for several hours.

My Asus laptop typically doesn’t show as charging when I plug it in unless the battery is below about 95%.

You could try discharging the battery for a bit - say to below 90% - then plug it in and check it charges.

I think this behaviour is driven by the bios, not the os.

Comment: Thx Willl, I thought about that but Windows confused me because it would charge all the way up to 100%. But on Ubuntu, laptop starts charging when its below 95% like you said it would

Answer (score -1):

I have the same issue. I did following things to resolve this.

- unplug power adapter for 5 minutes.
- press and hold power button for 30 seconds
- plug power adapter and start laptop.