# Hp Zbook 15 g3 laptop ubuntu 22.04.2 Battery not charging

Tags: 22.04, power-management, laptop, hp, battery

I have a problem changing my laptop (hp zbook 15 g3) on ubuntu
When the battery reach 95% or sometimes between (91%/97%) the battery stops charging and says (not charging)

I also tried pop os and i got the same problem

And I tried ubuntu and pop on my old laptop and the battery was charging normally on both

On windows it’s charge normal to 100%

The battery health is (78%) and it’s very good I don’t have sudden shutdown or The battery runs out quickly

Is that normal and if it doesn’t can you help me?

Comment: Have a look here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458349/battery-problems-with-ubuntu-22-04-2-lts/1461342#1461342 - I think that probably answers your question. Not sure why it's different between different laptops though!