# Battery charging status not showing

Tags: 22.04, power-management, laptop, battery, charging

I've just installed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS which was working fine but after the update the charging status is not showing.
The battery status shows **Not Charging** though its connected and charging. The health is frozen at 99% while the power is connected. I have no idea how to fix this. Can anyone help?
[screenshot of battery panel area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDKvT.png)

Comment: I think it’s probably covered here https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458349/battery-problems-with-ubuntu-22-04-2-lts/1461342#1461342

Comment: @Will They why sometime its shows and sometimes not ? And how someone will know whether the machine is connected with power supply or not?

Comment: I think if you connect with battery over about 97%, it won’t charge but it’ll run off power. I agree (re not knowing if power connected)  - that’s the downside … most laptops do have a led on the chassis that shows when power connected. You do of course know that it’s connected if the power doesn’t drop after 5 hours of use, but I agree it’s not very satisfactory. Try disconnecting the power, use it to say 90% battery, then connect power and see if the icon changes. My laptop is consistent in that behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by Will,Even though the charger is powered and plugged-in, some system disconnects the battery from the charger when it is reached 100% and it will reconnect charger somewhere between 95-98%(depends on the manufacturer) to maximise battery lifespan.
When the charger disconnects upower will report as either discharging or charge-pending and since the battery icon (battery status indicator) rely on upower it will change icon to discharging.(even though charger is plugged)

If your laptop supports battery charging threshold, you can install gnome extension **Battery Health Charging** to set charging threshold, but reason I am mentioning it, is because in the settings if has a feature **Change battery indicator icon behavior** when enabled, the battery indicator icon displays the status of charger connected (plugged in or not) rather than status of battery(discharging or not), so now you can know if charger is plugged or not.

Comment: Did the default behavior change from Ubuntu 18 or 20 to 22? I recently upgraded to 22 and started getting this "not charging" notice, which is not useful and is distracting because it makes me worried the laptop is not plugged in, when it is. Previously it showed an icon that visually communicated that the laptop was plugged in / on AC power. I would like to restore the old behavior as the new behavior is confusing and unintuitive. But I don't want to install an extension, especially when it used to work that way before the upgrade. This is a downgrade as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Tried in many ways, nothing works. Sometime its fine, sometimes not.

Sorry to share, but in my opinion- the linux system is kinda s***s in case for personal usage. It may be great for server and iot but there is problem everywhere and have to waste lots of time for tweaking and fixing different issues.