# In ubuntu 22.04 LTS My battery charging Indicator show not charging

Tags: laptop, battery, charging

Since my upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, the battery indicator shows "not charging" when the charger is plugged in while the battery is full. This could be correct but confusing. When the battery is not completely full and charging, it shows only the remaining battery life and percentage as if it was running from the battery
Does this is any Software glitch ???
because i also used Ubuntu 23 on same laptop there is no such problem i face.
only ubuntu 22.04 have this problem how to fix it......

Comment: Does it only show not charging when it’s fairly high, eg >90%, or whenever it’s plugged in whatever the battery status? And is the battery % increasing even when it says not charging? My Asus laptop doesn’t charge the battery unless it drops below about 95% - presumably to protect the battery against unnecessary charging. That’s bios behaviour not Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

That is a normal behavior for some laptops. I use a IdeaPad 330 at work and had that same "issue", at first I thought the plug was damaged. If you want a better explanation check these links.

[Battery charging status not showing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1466135/battery-charging-status-not-showing)

[Battery problems with Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1458349/battery-problems-with-ubuntu-22-04-2-lts/1461342#1461342)